# how do i create a custom date?

Tags: java, sql, datetime, date

need some help! this is sort of a 2 part question..

ive done a decent amount of programming but ive never really worked with dates, ive googled and all that but finding nothing.

part 1:

so lets say i have some variable:
Public Date adStartTime

i want it to be in this format: yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss
so i just do adStartTime = (some date formatter) + (2011/08/08 08:08:08) *which dont work

whats the proper way to get it to be that way?? i keep getting errors and such.. id prefer to do everything in Date instead of using strings/int..

part 2:

once i get the date in that format i will need to insert that into db, can i insert the date in that format? or will i need to change it?

reason i will need the time is because i am setting up automated ads for new company securities and sometimes the ad will run for one day or maybe 1/2 day so i will need to set the timer correctly.

thanks for any help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For part 1, use a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(datestring);
```

If you have code that looks anything like this, and still get errors, please edit your question to include your actual code.

For part 2, you should insert the date in the database as a Date, not as a String, so there is no format.

Comment: lols i kinda figured it out after i posted the questions, thanks!

question: do you think it is better to get a date string from user through a javascript form then parse it or just let user type the date in as DATE, i worry that user might put the wrong format or something and generate an error..

Comment: You're talking about a web app?  In most cases, I think it is much better to use a javascript datepicker than just a text input, as long as it is a good datepicker.  Expert users might prefer a simple text input to write in, but with a good datepicker it should be possible to ignore the picker and just write a date anyway.  If you use a text input, minimum usability is to at least tell the user exactly which format is expected.

Comment: does date picker have the time as well? because i need to be precise with year/month/day hour:minute:second

Comment: @JoeChen I think there are some datepickers that includes time.  But it is more common to put the time in a separate input after the date.

Answer (score 1):

1.) For working with dates I suggest you look at [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

which allows exactly that type of conversion .

for example

```
 public boolean isAfterPayDay(DateTime datetime) {
 if (datetime.getMonthOfYear() == 2) {   // February is month 2!!
   return datetime.getDayOfMonth() > 26;
 }
 return datetime.getDayOfMonth() > 28;
}
```

2.) for storing dateTimes in a DB there are several camps which hold different things

Some say you should store an int and convert . Joda makes that easy . Others ( like some oracle DBAs) seem to prefer a Date type. Joda handles that as well.  There is a discussion of some of the issues here [Date storage discussion](http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html)

How you actually do it can depend on your database type and the preferences of your DBA ( if you have one )

I would strongly suggest that you store datetime with a storage of Timezone .

Comment: In some cases, when there is need for complex manipulation and relations of dates, Joda time is nice (as Date has its drawbacks based on historical design flaws).  On the other hand, if you just need to pass dates around to stuff, most stuff expects java Dates, so its easier to stick with them and not add the complexity of having competing date implementations in the project.

Comment: @Rasmus The posted question seemed to appeal to one of the strengths of Joda. Converting an output to java Date is easily done and the time saved is well worth it .

Comment: Its a Open source library that your would have to add as a dependancy. URL to the JODA site is in my answer